# How to get the current record id value in URL field?

Tags: custom-field, custom-url

We are trying to get the current record ID value in custom URL field of that particular record. We tried this in formula field and its works fine but when tried this **in a custom URL field it's not working**.

Formula field:

```
HYPERLINK("https://c.cs14.visual.force.com/apex/Task_Manager_Report?id="& Id, 
"Click to Open TaskManager")
```

Comment: You can't use merge fields in non-formula fields. Perhaps you should try to explain what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the field as URL to be a "link" I think that you only could set the value using a trigger or workflow.

**Workflow**:

1. Set Evaluate the rule when a record is created
2. Add a field update task
3. use your previous formula
4. activate it

**Trigger** sample:

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account ( after insert) {
    for(Account a : Trigger.new){
      a.urlField__c = 'http://.....blahblah...'+ a.Id;
    }
}
```

Comment: This did not work for me. The trigger that you used here returns a 'System.FinalException: Record is read-only' error

Comment: @jan see http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23922/system-finalexception-record-is-read-only-trigger-updatecompetitors-line-24. Unfortunately if you're going to do this in a Trigger you have to take some care. If you want the field updated on all new records, this modification can't be done in a Before Insert trigger because the Id does not exist then. But records are read-only in an After Insert trigger. So the trick is to get the IDs of the records in the After Insert trigger, and make a new SOQL query and DML statement to update the records from inside the After Insert trigger.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to include the instance ID or fully qualified org path; this only leads to issues (for example, the URL will be different in sandbox vs. production, or when your sandbox name or instance changes, the link will not work).

To properly include the full path as a clickable link without a redirect, simply create a new Formula field of type text, then enter the formula with the relative path. For example, to be able to have a clickable "Lead Name" field on Leads, create a custom formula text field that uses this formula:

HYPERLINK("/lightning/r/Lead/" & CASESAFEID(Id) & "/view", "Lead", "_blank")

This will allow you to use the field "Lead Name" in reports or page layouts, as a field users can click on it to open the record in a new window.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It should work

HYPERLINK('https://c.cs14.visual.force.com/apex/Task_Manager_Report?id='+Id , 'Click to Open TaskManager')

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a Formula Field (with Text return) instead a URL field so that you can use HYPERLINK function in following way:

```
HYPERLINK("your_URL" & CASESAFEID(Id), "Text_to_view")
```

Answer (score -1):

change HYPERLINK to url.and try it again.
I think this will help to capture record id
BrowserURL=BrowserURL.right(15);//Pull from right the 15 digit Id

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please explain me more on this. We don't want to use formula field need to use only custom URL field.

Comment: When giving an answer, some more explanation may be usefull. For instance explain why URL() works differently or some references to documentation can improve the quality of your answer.

Comment: see the edited reply