# Execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only: Trigger

Tags: apex, exception

I have write a trigger on Company__c.
**My code**
**

```
Trigger DirectOrderRFMS on Company__c(AFTER INSERT,AFTER UPDATE)  
{

 FOR(Company__c com  :  TRIGGER.NEW)
 {
        If(com.Subject__c.startsWith('S') || com.Subject__c.startsWith('R') )
    {
          com.Description = '*** IMPORTANT***'; //Runtime ecxeption
          //SOME OTHER LOGIC  
    }
 }
}
```

Why this is came I don't no.Any SFDC limitation are their?

Comment: See http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23922/system-finalexception-record-is-read-only-trigger-updatecompetitors-line-24.

Answer (score 1):

You can only update fields on the trigger context objects during **before** triggers, not during **after** triggers.

To decide if you should use a before or after trigger the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers.htm) provides the following guidelines.

> Triggers can be divided into two types:
>
> - Before triggers can be used to update or validate record values before they are saved to the database.
> - After triggers can be used to access field values that are set by the database (such as a record's Id or lastUpdated field), and to affect changes in other records, such as logging into an audit table or firing asynchronous events with a queue.