# Assigning an input value to standard/custom field dynamically

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm working on custom workflow field update
I have taken the value to update as input field and by using the `map<>` method I'm getting the `api` name of the field and storing it in a record
Now I need to take dynamically the field to update and the value to update from the records of the custom object in which I have save them
for eg
Suppose the Field_to_Update__c is "department" & Value_to_Update__c is "dept"
I've save them in field as

```
a.put(objRuleFieldUpdate.Field_Udpate__r.Field_to_Update__c,objRuleFieldUpdate.Field_Udpate__r.Value_to_Update__c);
```

In the above line `objRuleFieldUpdate` is instance of junction object `Field_Udpate__r` is the custom object. I'm taking the relation to access its field. The trigger is saved without error
Now when I try to create a record in contact matching the workflow criteria it give the error as below on the above line

```
Apex trigger ContactFieldUpdate caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: ContactFieldUpdate: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only: Trigger.ContactFieldUpdate
```

how can I achieve this functionality of taking the field to update dynamically and value to update dynamically and then assign the value to the field.

**NEW EDIT :**

I agree I've check the code & that's not working if the new record is created. But I have already created the records i'm fetching the records from the database. I'm taking the records that meet the criteria in the list & then I'm updating the field

```
List<Object1__c> lstOfObject = [ SELECT  Id, Object__c, Rule_Evaluation_Criteria__c, Status__c,
                                      (SELECT Id, Object2__r.Name, Object2__r.Object__c, Object2__r.Field__c,
                                       Object2__r.Operator__c, Object2__r.Value__c FROM Object1_Object2_JO__r),
                                      (SELECT Id, Object3__r.Rule_Name__c, Object3__r.Object_Name__c,
                                       Object3__r.Field_to_Update__c, Object3__r.Value_to_Update__c 
                                       FROM Object1_Object2_JO__r)
                                      FROM Object1__c
                                      WHERE Object__c = 'Contact' AND Rule_Evaluation_Criteria__c = 'Record is    
                                      Created' AND Status__c = 'Active'
                                    ];
```

This is the query that I'm using to get the records using the junction objects
I've created a code if else condition to match the criteria that is entered

Once the criteria is met a field will be update so this is the code I'm using to update the field

```
for(Object1_Object3_JO__c objObject1Object3JO : objObject1.objObject1Object3JO __r)
                {
                    if(isInCriteria==True)
                    {
                        a.put(objObject1Object3JO.Object3__r.Field_to_Update__c,objObject1Object3JO.Object3__r.Value_to_Update__c);

                        //String fieldtoupdate = String.valueOf(a.get(objRuleFieldUpdate.Field_Udpate__r.Field_to_Update__c));
                        //System.debug('-----------------'+fieldtoupdate);
                        //Schema.DescribeFieldResult field1=mapFields.get(objRuleFieldUpdate.Field_Udpate__r.Field_to_Update__c).getDescribe();
                        //a.get(field1.getName()) = '';
                        //objRuleFieldUpdate.Field_Udpate__r.Value_to_Update__c;
                        //System.debug('-----FIELD1------'+field1);
                        //System.debug('-----------------'+objRuleFieldUpdate.Field_Udpate__r.Value_to_Update__c);

                        //Schema.DescribeFieldResult field1 = mapFields.get(objRuleFieldUpdate.Field_Update__r.Field_to_Update__c).getDescribe();
                        //a.Field_to_Update__c = objRuleFieldUpdate.Value_to_Update__c;
                    }
                }
```

`isInCriteria` is the flag that will get true once the criteria is met

```
objObject1Object3JO.Object3__r.Field_to_Update__c
```

This variable stores the name of the field to update

```
objObject1Object3JO.Object3__r.Value_to_Update__c
```

This variable stores the value to assign to that field

Comment: rYou can not update fields in after update trigger please use before update. Your question is duplicate of this link.
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23922/system-finalexception-record-is-read-only-trigger-updatecompetitors-line-24

Comment: Updated the Question with code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System.FinalException: Record is read-only: Trigger.updateCompetitors: line 24](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23922/system-finalexception-record-is-read-only-trigger-updatecompetitors-line-24)