# trigger is not executing successfully

Tags: apex, trigger, triggercontext

If I use the below code then it throws an error:

> Review all error messages below to correct your data. Apex trigger
>   abc caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: abc :
>   execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.FinalException: Record is
>   read-only: Class.xyz: line 93, column 1

```
if((trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate) && trigger.isBefore)
{
    B2C_ServiceRoleService.encryptData(trigger.new); 
}
if(trigger.isinsert || trigger.isbefore){
    B2C_ServiceRoleService.copyAccountFields(trigger.new);
}
```

If I use below code then it works fine.

```
if((trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate) && trigger.isBefore)
{
    B2C_ServiceRoleService.encryptData(trigger.new); 
    B2C_ServiceRoleService.copyAccountFields(trigger.new);
}
```

- Value of `trigger.isinsert` = `true` in both scenarios
- Value of `trigger.isupdate` = `false` in both scenarios
- Value of `trigger.isbefore` = `true` in both scenarios

I am not able to figure out why it throws an error in the first case. I encounter the error when I create new records.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: records should be created but getting below error:
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Apex trigger abc caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: abc : execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only: Class.xyz: line 93, column 1

Comment: B2C_ServiceRoleService.copyAccountFields(trigger.new); runs when isInsert is true and isBefore is false.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.FinalException: Record is read-only: Trigger.updateCompetitors: line 24](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23922/system-finalexception-record-is-read-only-trigger-updatecompetitors-line-24)

Comment: even if it is isinsert= true or isbefore= true it is going inside  method 
B2C_ServiceRoleService.copyAccountFields(trigger.new);

Comment: Then in 2nd scenario also it should not work.i am not getting read only error for 2nd scenario.

Comment: In first case it will go in B2C_ServiceRoleService.copyAccountFields(trigger.new); in case of isInsert is true and isBefore false. It will be after insert, which cause the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36959/discussion-between-chiz-and-robert-barnett).

Answer (score 2):

I believe that problem is here:

```
if(trigger.isinsert || trigger.isbefore){
    B2C_ServiceRoleService.copyAccountFields(trigger.new);
}
```

Your condition means that this line of code will be executed for all `insert` and all `before` events, including `before delete`, which does not have a `Trigger.new`, which is giving you error I believe

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, I assume that you do some modification to these records(`Trigger.new`) in your method(`copyAccountFields()`), which is not allowed in an `after` trigger, which will stil be executed, because `after insert` does return `true` for `insert OR before`

Comment: But i am not doing any delete of records.I am trying to create a new records then these errors are coming.

Comment: @RobertBarnett edited my answer

Comment: I am not deleting any records.I am just creating a new record.@Novarg

Answer (score 0):

As already noted, when you evaluate `trigger.isInsert || trigger.isBefore` it is true for the following trigger states:

- `before insert`
- `before update`
- `before delete`
- `after insert`

This is why trigger handler patterns are more tidy. You can at least move your code to an evaluation like the following so that it is more explicit which events correspond to which actions:

```
if (trigger.isBefore)
{
    if (trigger.isInsert)
    {
        // handle beforeInsert
    }
    if (trigger.isUpdate)
    {
        // handle beforeUpdate
    }
}
if (trigger.isAfter)
{
    if (trigger.isInsert)
    {
        // handle afterInsert
    }
    if (trigger.isUpdate)
    {
        // handle afterUpdate
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It should be like below then it will work fine.We need to use 'trigger.isinsert && trigger.isbefore' in 2nd if condition

```
if((trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate) && trigger.isBefore)
    {
        B2C_ServiceRoleService.encryptData(trigger.new); 

    }
    if(trigger.isinsert && trigger.isbefore){
        B2C_ServiceRoleService.copyAccountFields(trigger.new);
    }
```

And problem was trigger.isinsert was true and hence it was going inside afterinsert part and as we know on afterinsert fields are readonly so it was not able to insert data into those fields so once we put && condition we made sure it is not going to afterinsert part of trigger.