# What is missing from my mapping?

Tags: query, map

When I update a "Payment" object, which has a field for the "Order" it is related to, I want an "Account" field on the Payment taken from a lookup on its related Order.

I don't want to do queries for every trigger.New to avoid limits.

I used very, very similar code -- almost identical -- for mapping information similarly in another project. However, I'm having an issue with a null pointer here, but I know the object isn't null, so I must be missing something.

```
trigger PaymentInsert on Payment__c (after update) {

Set<Id> servIDs = new Set<Id>();
for (Payment__c pay : trigger.new){
    servIDs.add(pay.Service_Invoice__c);
    System.debug('The Invoice: ' + pay.service_invoice__c);
}

System.debug(servIDs);
Map<Id, Order2__c> invoices = new Map<Id, Order2__c>([SELECT Account_Name__c, ID FROM Order2__c WHERE Id IN :servIDs]);
for(payment__c current: trigger.new){
    Order2__c thisOne = invoices.get(current.ID);
    System.debug('This one: ' + thisOne);
    if(thisOne.Account_Name__c != null){
        System.debug('Not Null');
        current.Account__c = thisOne.Account_Name__c;
    }
}
```

Where I print 'the Invoice ', it is not null. There is only one pair of records (payment/service invoice) being invoked here, so that simplifies it. When I call invoices.get(current.ID), that's null. I'm wondering how I actually make the mapping between an ID and its invoice. This code worked somewhere else with different objects, and I'm wondering what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are trying to get the `Order2__c` record by using the ID of the `Payment__c`. I suspect if you  use the `service_invoice__c` field from `Payment__c` to do the get instead it will resolve your issue (I'm assuming that it is a lookup to the invoice). Suggested code below.

```
trigger PaymentInsert on Payment__c (after update) {

Set<Id> servIDs = new Set<Id>();
for (Payment__c pay : trigger.new){
    servIDs.add(pay.Service_Invoice__c);
    System.debug('The Invoice: ' + pay.service_invoice__c);
}

System.debug(servIDs);
Map<Id, Order2__c> invoices = new Map<Id, Order2__c>([SELECT Account_Name__c, ID FROM Order2__c WHERE Id IN :servIDs]);
for(payment__c current: trigger.new){
    Order2__c thisOne = invoices.get(current.Service_Invoice__c);
    System.debug('This one: ' + thisOne);
    if(thisOne.Account_Name__c != null){
        System.debug('Not Null');
        current.Account__c = thisOne.Account_Name__c;
    }
}
```

**Edit**

The second issue you will have arises from the fact that you are attempting to edit the record (by changing `current.Account__c`) during the `after` trigger context. This [cannot be done in the way you are trying to do it](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23922/system-finalexception-record-is-read-only-trigger-updatecompetitors-line-24) because the record is read-only in that context. The simples solution would be to change the trigger context to `before update`. Alternatively you'd need to query the Payment records separately and explicitly perform a DML operation on them.

Comment: Not quite -- if the ID of the payment is the Key and it corresponds to a service invoice (Order2__c), then the Order thisOne should the the associated Service invoice from current.ID (key)

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. Have you done `System.debug()` on both the invoices Map and the current.Id value to ensure they match as you describe?

Comment: I'm not sure how to debug with the map specificially. I have written out what I have tested. Again, I've tested the Serv. Invoice as it is added to the list of them, in that initial loop. It has a valid ID, and when I look up that ID, that object has a value for Account_Name__c. So neither should be null. Once I make it into the loop, 'thisOne' is null, as is, subsequently, its account name

Comment: Does it definitely log `null` when you make the change I suggested? Looking through it again I'm fairly confident my answer is correct. Your Payment object is joined to an Order by the Service Invoice field which stores the ID of the Order. To get the related Order record you should be using the value of that field and not the Payment Id. Id's in Salesforce are unique so the Payment Id will not be the same as the Order Id.

Comment: That's so weird -- sorry I doubted you, it totally worked (Except I got a read-only error on something I was trying to change...I can work with that). I'll try to figure out why. In my mind, invoices.get() would take a key (payment Id) and return its corresponding elements (order/service invoice). 2 questions -- where is it actually associating a payment ID with the correct Service invoice?

Actually...I understand that now, how it works. Thanks! Still wondering how it automatically associates them without any put methods :)

Comment: It says  current.Account__c = thisOne.Account_Name__c; returns a Read-Only error.....I checked, and current is the Payment, and the account name field isn't read only. Suggestions..?

Comment: That will be because you are using an `after update` trigger which means that [the field values are read-only](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23922/system-finalexception-record-is-read-only-trigger-updatecompetitors-line-24).  Given that you are only using update so therefore have the record Ids I can't see why changing to `before update` would not work. That should solve the issue.

Comment: Edit: whoops. embarrassing. Trigger inactive.