# Case owner not able to change case owner after insert

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, case, after-trigger

I am trying change the case ownerid to Queue but getting System.FinalException: Record is read-only error in after insert.

Below is the my code:

```
if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter)
        {    
            Map<String, Id> mapQueues = new Map<String, Id>();
            for(Group grp: [select Id, name, Type from Group where Type = 'Queue']){
                mapQueues.put(grp.name, grp.id);
            }

            for(Case caseObject : Trigger.New)
            {
                if(caseObject.Complaint_type__c == 'Complaint About Services Through Centers'){
                    caseObject.OwnerId = mapQueues.get('Licensing Department');
                }
                else if(caseObject.Complaint_type__c=='Consumer Protection Complaint'){
                    caseObject.OwnerId = mapQueues.get('Monitoring and Consumer Protection');
                }
                else if(caseObject.Complaint_type__c=='Online Services'){
                    caseObject.OwnerId = mapQueues.get('IT Department');
                }
                else {
                    caseObject.OwnerId = mapQueues.get('Support Team');
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: I’ve had this myself and it was a matter of context like: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23922/system-finalexception-record-is-read-only-trigger-updatecompetitors-line-24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Record is read only in `after trigger` context. Refer [Context Variable Considerations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables_considerations.htm)

So, you need to separately query the case records to update. Here is the approach.

```
if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter)
{    
    Map<String, Id> mapQueues = new Map<String, Id>();
    for(Group grp: [select Id, name, Type from Group where Type = 'Queue']){
        mapQueues.put(grp.name, grp.id);
    }

    List<Case> lstCase = [SELECT id, Complaint_type__c, OwnerId FROM Case WHER Id IN:Trigger.NewMap.keyset()];

    for(Case caseObject : lstCase)
    {
        if(caseObject.Complaint_type__c == 'Complaint About Services Through Centers'){
            caseObject.OwnerId = mapQueues.get('Licensing Department');
        }
        else if(caseObject.Complaint_type__c=='Consumer Protection Complaint'){
            caseObject.OwnerId = mapQueues.get('Monitoring and Consumer Protection');
        }
        else if(caseObject.Complaint_type__c=='Online Services'){
            caseObject.OwnerId = mapQueues.get('IT Department');
        }
        else {
            caseObject.OwnerId = mapQueues.get('Support Team');
        }
    }
    update lstCase;
}
```