# Updating after Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger, read-only

I've tried updating the data after the data is edited in my listview using trigger.and some columns are read only .i want to update a picklist in the object when the record is updated in the list view.
and my code is

```
trigger updateSegment on Opt_Segment__c (after update){
for(Opt_Segment__c updatedSegment:Trigger.new)
{
    updatedSegment.Valid__c='Override';
}
}
```

And i'm getting error as
[image]

can anyone help me how to resolve this error /is there any other way to achieve this...
Thanks...:)

Answer (score 0):

You caanot update same reference in After trigger. Following code shall work -

```java
trigger updateSegment on Opt_Segment__c (before update){
  for(Opt_Segment__c updatedSegment:Trigger.new)
  {
    updatedSegment.Valid__c='Override';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23922/system-finalexception-record-is-read-only-trigger-updatecompetitors-line-24#:%7E:text=This%20is%20because%20you%20are,not%20committed%2C%20to%20the%20database.) that has a similar error there is a description of why this is happening to which you can have a look.

Apart from using before insert below is the explanation in above link:

"This is because you are in an after insert/update trigger and the records are read only in that context as they have been written, but not committed, to the database.

Unfortunately your trigger is relying on the ids of the records, which means you won't be able to use before insert as the ids won't be populated at that time (as the records haven't been written to the database at that point so while you can write to them, database generated fields aren't populated).

In this instance you'll need to clone the record (or query anew via SOQL) and make changes to the new copy of the record, then execute the update against the new copies."